How do you programmatically pause the debugger from the debugged script and inspect the stack of every active thread?
I have a really determined glitch that occurs in conjunction with me seeing The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. printed to the console - which happens when the script has been running for a couple of hours. So I need a way of "pausing" the script so I can inspect it and see whats causing the glitch.
I'm currently running the following setup:
originalPrint=print # @todo Remove when finished debugging
def print_(*args,**kwargs):
    originalPrint(f"printing:{args}{kwargs}")
    originalPrint(*args,**kwargs)
__builtins__["print"]=print_

In hopes that whatever is printing the message I see in console uses pythons built in print statement. If that turns out to be the case, how would I modify this function to "pause" the script in a way that lets me inspect the stack frames of all running threads within the program?
Also, if I can be picky it would be nice if I could use Visual Studio Code's debug view to inspect the stack frames, but I'm genuinely desperate so any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated.

You can import the pdb module and use pdb.set_trace() to enter debugger mode.
